# tinydb search,insert,update errors

Tags: python, tinydb

in the console it gives me the error that "inventory" does not have the "search" command but as you can see from the images "inventory" is a table of the db and also when I try to do "insert, search, update" it gives me the same error. Can you help me?

error:

```
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBots\bot\TestBot\testbot.py", line 81, in find
    result = inventory.search(Inventory.name == "common_square")
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'search'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'search'
```

code1:

```
db = TinyDB('testdb.json')
Database = Query()
Inventory = Query()
inventory = TinyDB.table(db,'inventory')
```

code2:

```
if c_cards_rdm == 2:
                image = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/873309423555194910/873309521693536306/common_square.png'
                result = inventory.search(Inventory.name == "common_square")
                if str(result) == '[]':
                    inventory.insert({"name":"common_square","quantity":"1","atk":"0","def":"35"})
                else:
                    inventory.update({"quantity":f"{str(int(result[0]['quantity'])+1)}"}, 
                    Inventory.name == "common_square")
```

Comment: Please show us a complete example that reproduces this error. It looks like you're probably overwriting the `inventory` variable at some point, but we can't tell. That seems extra likely since you already have two variables named `inventory` that differ only by case (`Inventory` and `inventory`), which seems likely to lead to confusion.

Comment: I tried to change "Inventory" but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Again, you need to show us runnable code that reproduces the problem. Otherwise we're just guessing.